# Extracting data.frames from a list using for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list and I have managed to extract a data.frame for the first matrix "`t`" using:

```
forecast_t<-as.data.frame(forecast$t)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do it to the rest of the elements using :

```
for (i in t,ws,wdir,hs,tp,tz,mdir) {
    forecast_i<-as.data.frame(forecast$i)

}
```

Thank you

Comment: `platypus`' answer is the way to go to do exactly that, but this is overall a very bad idea. You'll be much better off keeping everything in one list, rather than cluttering your workspace. Something like `lapply(forecast, as.data.frame)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it

```
for (i in c("t","ws","wdir","hs","tp","tz","mdir")) {
  assign(paste0("forecast_",i),as.data.frame(forecast[[i]]))
}
```

Comment: Please see `fortunes::fortune(236)`: _The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign function._